# Django admin dependable dropdown

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

So I'm trying to make a dependable dropdown for django admin,
and when i select a province the console shows the following error:
405 method not allowed

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"detail\":\"Method \\\"GET\\\" not allowed.\"}","responseJSON":{"detail":"Method \"GET\" not allowed."},"status":405,"statusText":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

the related codes are as given below and the method is POST on both the ajax function and View but it says GET method is not allowed
the `models.py` is as:

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("province")
        verbose_name_plural = _("provinces")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class District(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("district")
        verbose_name_plural = _("districts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SchoolProfile(models.Model):
    """
    School detail model
    """
    .....other_fields....
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        blank=True,
        null = True,
        verbose_name = _("province")
    )
    district = models.ForeignKey(
        District, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        blank=True,
        null = True,
        verbose_name = _("district")
    )
```

and on `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(SchoolProfile)
class SchoolProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ServerInline, ServerUpdateInline]
    list_display = [...]
        class Media:
        js=("school/dependent-dropdown-ajax.js",)
```

`views.py`

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django.http import JsonResponse

class DistrictList(APIView):
    permission_classed=[IsAuthenticated,]
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        province=request.data['province']
        district={}
        if province:
            districts=Province.objects.get(id=province).districts.all()
            district={p.name:p.id for p in districts}
        return JsonResponse(data=district, safe=False)
```

`urls.py`

```
    url(r'^districts/$', DistrictList.as_view(), name='districts'),
```

`dependent-dropdown-ajax.js` the js file is correctly loaded and the console log in the following is running

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

jQuery(function($){
    console.log('here')
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_province").on('change', function() {
            console.log("Province changed");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/school/districts/",
                type:"POST",
                data:{province: $(this).val(),},
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    cols = document.getElementById("id_district");
                    cols.options.length = 0;
                    cols.options.add(new Option("District", "District"));
                    for(var k in result){
                        cols.options.add(new Option(k, result[k]));
                    }
                },
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
                },
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I think you have an issue in your ajax url call, you have added /school/ try removing it and its best to use a get call with get method in your api view.

Comment: No, the url is actually correct that's how the url in school app is setup

Comment: Did you checked what is the complete url coming in your browser developer tools  network tab? Is that the correct url? Can you access that url apart from ajax call? If I try your above code removing school everything works fine also try accessing the url with namespace. That will throw an error with url resolver which may help in debugging the issue.

Comment: Yes the url is actually correct and i checked it in the browser

Comment: @DanishHasan can you also take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897343/django-chained-dropdown-implementation-on-django-admin . Its another implementation i'm trying for the same functionality