# Django Chained Dropdown implementation on Django admin

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

the issue I'm facing is I set a district and the city which is under the district and save it. It saves correctly to the database. And when I come back to the page and change the city and save, the city is set to null and the district too is set to null in the database
How do I solve it
Context: Trying to overwrite Django-admin `change_form` for `SchoolProfileForm` and for the dependable dropdown of the province, district, city, and ward. when trying to change the already saved city from before, the district value is reset to nothing, and also the city's value(the same issue with the ward, the city is also reset)

Javascript Functions:

```
function resetDistrict() {
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    let district_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
    $('#select2-id_district-container').html(district_list);
    console.log(district_list)
}

function getDistrict(province_id) {
    resetDistrict()
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/school/district/' + province_id, function (resp){
        let district_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
        $.each(resp.data, function(i, item){
            district_list += '<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ item.name +'</option>'
        });
        $('#id_district').html(district_list);
    });
}

function getDistrictfromDb(province_id) {
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/school/district/' + province_id, function (resp){
        let district_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
        $.each(resp.data, function(i, item){
            district_list += '<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ item.name +'</option>'
        });
        $('#id_district').html(district_list);
    });
}

function resetCity() {
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    let city_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
    $('#select2-id_city-container').html(city_list);
    console.log(city_list)
}

function getCity(district_id) {
    resetCity();
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/school/city/' + district_id, function (resp){
        let city_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
        $.each(resp.data, function(i, item){
            city_list += '<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ item.name +'</option>'
        });
        $('#id_city').html(city_list);
    });
}

function getCityfromDb(district_id) {
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/school/city/' + district_id, function (resp){
        let city_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
        $.each(resp.data, function(i, item){
            city_list += '<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ item.name +'</option>'
        });
        $('#id_city').html(city_list);
    });
}

function resetWard() {
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    let ward_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
    $('#select2-id_ward-container').html(ward_list);
    console.log(ward_list)
}

function getWard(city_id) {
    resetWard()
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/school/ward/' + city_id, function (resp){
        let ward_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
        $.each(resp.data, function(i, item){
            ward_list += '<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ item.name +'</option>'
        });
        $('#id_ward').html(ward_list);
    });
}

function getWardfromDb(city_id) {
    let $ = django.jQuery;
    $.get('/school/ward/' + city_id, function (resp){
        let ward_list = '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>'
        $.each(resp.data, function(i, item){
            ward_list += '<option value="'+ item.id +'">'+ item.name +'</option>'
        });
        $('#id_ward').html(ward_list);
    });
}
```

and the forms.py to overwrite django admin form:

```
class SchoolProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SchoolProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SchoolProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # when there is instance key, select the default value
        # Province always loaded for initial data, 
        # because Province is on the first level 
        try:
            self.initial['province'] = kwargs['instance'].province.id
        except:
            pass
        province_list = [('', '---------')] + [(i.id, i.name) for i in Province.objects.all()]

        # District, City, and Ward are on the child level, 
        # it will be loaded when user click the parent level
        try:
            self.initial['district'] = kwargs['instance'].district.id
            district_init_form = [(i.id, i.name) for i in District.objects.filter(
                province=kwargs['instance'].province
            )]
        except:
            district_init_form = [('', '---------')]

        try:
            self.initial['city'] = kwargs['instance'].city.id
            city_init_form = [(i.id, i.name) for i in City.objects.filter(
                district=kwargs['instance'].district
            )]
        except:
            city_init_form = [('', '---------')]

        try:
            self.initial['ward'] = kwargs['instance'].ward.id
            ward_init_form = [(i.id, i.name) for i in Ward.objects.filter(
                city=kwargs['instance'].city
            )]
        except:
            ward_init_form = [('', '---------')]

        # Overriding the form, adding onchange attribute to call the ajax function
        self.fields['province'].widget = forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'id': 'id_province',
                'class': 'location-select',
                'onchange': 'getDistrict(this.value);',
            },
            choices=province_list,
        )
        self.fields['district'].widget = forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'id': 'id_district',
                'class': 'location-select',
                'onchange': 'getCity(this.value);',
            },
            choices=district_init_form
        )
        self.fields['city'].widget = forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'id': 'id_city',
                'class': 'location-select',
                'onchange': 'getWard(this.value);',
            },
            choices=city_init_form
        )
        self.fields['ward'].widget = forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'id': 'id_ward',
                'class': 'location-select',
            },
            choices=ward_init_form
        )
        self.fields['locale'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'id': 'id_locale',
                'width': '200px',
            },
        )
```

`views.py`

```
def province_list(request):
    province = Province.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse({'data':[{'id': p.id, 'name': p.name} for p in province ]})

def district_list(request, province_id):
    district = District.objects.filter(province_id=province_id)
    return JsonResponse({'data': [{'id': d.id, 'name': d.name} for d in district ]})

def city_list(request, district_id):
    city = City.objects.filter(district_id=district_id)
    return JsonResponse({'data': [{'id': c.id, 'name': c.name} for c in city]})

def ward_list(request, city_id):
    ward = Ward.objects.filter(city_id=city_id)
    return JsonResponse({'data': [{'id': w.id, 'name': w.name} for w in ward ]})
```

Comment: Please share model code and you can remove try except code by identify add/change form using self.instance.pk is not None. If it is true then it is change form else add form.

Comment: One way to  implement dependent dropdown is- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736218/how-to-filter-dropdown-choices-based-on-the-value-of-another-dropdown-in-django/74739876#74739876

Answer (score 0):

Full integrated in my git-hub repository and presented on DjangoCon 2022 US.
https://youtu.be/5r1jNJzVHBU?t=1789

I use AtocompleteWidget instead of base select, and patch django based autocomplete JS